# How to read graphic image from database and paste it to clipboard as a file?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, clipboard

I have a database table with the following columns: idCompany:INT, Data:LONGBLOB, Extension:VARCHAR(5), Name:VARCHAR(45).

I have succeded to persist an image into mysql using entity framework:

```
public static void PersistCurrentImage(Company company, FileStream logoStream, MyEntities context)
    {
        if (logoStream != null)
        {
            //reading
            byte[] data = new byte[logoStream.Length];
            logoStream.Read(data, 0, Convert.ToInt32(logoStream.Length));
            logoStream.Close();

            //setting image
            company.CompanyLogo = new CompanyLogo();
            company.CompanyLogo.Image = data;
            company.CompanyLogo.Extension = Path.GetExtension(logoStream.Name);
            company.CompanyLogo.Name = Path.GetFileName(logoStream.Name);

            context.SaveChanges();

        }
    }
```

What I would like to do is to get the image from database, make a file out of it and place it in the clipboard, so later I can paste the file.

I have looked for a solution for 1 hour but I can seem to find it. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have solved it. First by writing the image to the hard drive and then copying it to the clipboard.

```
public static void CopyLogo(Company company)
    {
        if (company.CompanyLogo != null)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(company.CompanyLogo.Image, 0, company.CompanyLogo.Image.Length);

            using (ms)
            {
                //saving image on current project directory
                Image img = Image.FromStream(ms);
                img.Save(Environment.CurrentDirectory+"\\"+ company.CompanyLogo.Name);

                //copying to clipboard
                StringCollection paths = new StringCollection();
                paths.Add(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\" + company.CompanyLogo.Name);
                Clipboard.SetFileDropList(paths);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Ah, never saw your answer. Only when I submitted mine.

Answer (score 1):

I had success with code like this:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(@"logo.jpg", company.CompanyLogo.Image.ToArray());
StringCollection paths = new StringCollection();
paths.Add("logo.jpg");
Clipboard.SetFileDropList(paths);
```

Now the file is in clipboard as though you had done ctrl-C in the explorer.

This assumes that the logo was a jpg, and in my case the image was stored as Sql Server's `image` data type. I think MySql's `LONGBLOB` behaves the same way. Note that you should use complete paths (omitted here for brevity.